# How to point a <img> src to an image when using mod_rewrite to redirect all URLs to a php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a directory application in php and have every URL redirected to index.php using mod_rewrite.

```
#Redirect to index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am trying to have it so that if a user enters the URL of an image that is actually there, it will send them to a page within my theme that has the image displayed in a div. I originally had these two lines in my .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Having these though makes any file accessable. Currently when I try to access the image through a image tag, I get the correct code in view source, `<img src='testImage.png'>`, however the image does not display. Is there some way that I can accomplish this or will I just have to re-add the two rewrite conditions and not have the image viewed in my template? Am I shooting for too much? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `RewriteCond` to exclude specific file extensions like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpg|\.png)$ [NC]
```

Be sure to extend it with all the image extensions you want to allow.

Comment: I've thought about that but that wouldn't allow me to make the image display in my theme. Could it be that what I want isn't possible?

Comment: I don't get that question. Why would it not make it possible to display the image in your theme?

Comment: I simply mean that I want it so that if the user enters the URL of the image, instead of just the image, I would like the image to show up in a page. It seems that it is not possible. Thanks for the rewrite condition. That will help.